# Reference for Hammett acidities of dilute H2SO4?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, reference-request

When $\ce{H2SO4}$ is dissolved in water in little amounts ($<\pu{1M}$), the $\mathrm{pH}$ scale can be used to measure the acidity of the solution. However, in larger concentrations, this breaks down and we have to use the Hammett acidity instead.

I have found [this thesis](https://macsphere.mcmaster.ca/bitstream/11375/19972/1/Peel_Terence_E._1971Sept_Ph.D..pdf), which has a table of $\mathrm{H_0}$ (Hammett acidity function) values for 95% and higher $\ce{H2SO4}$.

However, I would like a table with Hammett acidites of more dilute systems, like 70% $\ce{H2SO4}$ and 50% $\ce{H2SO4}$. Is there a reference for this?

Comment: [Figure 1 on p. 8 in your PDF](https://macsphere.mcmaster.ca/bitstream/11375/19972/1/Peel_Terence_E._1971Sept_Ph.D..pdf#page=21) already contains a plot of $H_0$ function for the concentration range from 0 to 100%. What else do you want to know?

Comment: Didn't notice that, thanks. But a table with precise values would be better.

Comment: Check the *Typical Values* section in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_acidity_function).