# How does the Hammett acidity function work and how to calculate it for [H2SO4] = 1,830? Any references?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, theoretical-chemistry, reference-request

I'm modelling the concentrations in the Belousov Zhabotinsky reaction. For this model, I need to convert [BrO3-] to [HBrO3]. I discovered in several papers that the following correlation applies:

$$ [\ce{HBrO3}] = \frac{h0}{h_0+0.2} * [\ce{BrO3^-}]_0 $$

See for example [this dissertation on page 28](https://cordis.europa.eu/docs/projects/cnect/2/248992/080/deliverables/001-D23.pdf) or [this paper on page 2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12225987_Oscillatory_clusters_in_a_model_of_the_photosensitive_Belousov-Zhabotinsky_reaction_system_with_global_feedback).

I have a solution which has $[\ce{H2SO4}]$ = 0.915M (I assume $[\ce{H+}]$ = 1,830 M).

My $[\ce{BrO3^-}]$ was 0,2411 M.

I researched the Hammett Acidity function, but I still don't completely understand the concept. What I do know is that $h_0$ substitutes for $[H+]$ and that $h_0$ has the unit of M.

Can anyone explain the concept of this function in a bit more detail and explain in what way it exactly relates to pH (and therefore to H+)?

On the internet I found [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp901318z), which says that $h_0$ = 3 when $[\ce{H2SO4}]$ = 1.5M. Are there any other tables or references with $h_0$ related to the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ or $\ce{H2SO4}$? There is [one more question on SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/126731/reference-for-hammett-acidities-of-dilute-h2so4) about Hammett acidity. This question links to tables with $h_0$ for certain % of H2SO4. Can I perhaps use that? How does $[\ce{H2SO4}]$ relate to a % of H2SO4?

Is there a way to calculate the $h_0$ when $[\ce{H2SO4}]=1.830 M$?

Comment: Just plug pH-meter in there and used the values you get - H0 is approx. = pH for diluted sol.

Comment: Oke, thanks @Mithoron! So in this case, I assume H3O+ = 1.830 M, my pH = -log(1.830) = -0.262 and I can assume h0 = -0.262? Because when h0 = -.262, the [HBrO3] would be 1,01 and that's about four times the amount of BrO3- I added... But well, you're perhaps the wrong person to ask this, whilst you didn't devise the formula Thanks anyway!

Comment: As Karsten mentioned, you assume wrong, more so H2SO4 is *not* the only thing affecting pH in such mixture.

Comment: Hi Mithoron, thanks for pointing that out again. The formule here is about the initial concentrations, so you kind of cancel out the other things affecting pH in such a mixture. I'm just secondary school and there we assume that H2SO4 completely becomes H+. As this thing isn't at a very advanced level, I'll for now just assume H0=[H+].

Answer (score 1):

> I have a solution which has $[\ce{H2SO4}]$ = 0.915M (I assume $[\ce{H+}]$ = 1,830 M).

While $\ce{H2SO4}$ is a strong acid, $\ce{HSO4-}$ is not ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ around 2). So your pH should be about zero, and you might not need to use the Hammett acidity at all.

Comment: Hi Karsten, thanks for thinking along. The thing is that I need to calculate the HBrO3 concentration. One of the ways I could do this is by using the aforementioned formula. Because of that I do need to use the Hammett Acidity function. Would that mean that my Hammet acidity function is roughly zero? And is there a way of calculating that?